# Popup partial view on mouse move and hide on mouse out

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm pretty new to javascript and am running into a problem with my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I want to dynamically display a list of skills (in a category) for a project when the user hovers over that project's skill category. Here are my 2 questions:

**1.**
Right now the jquery will pop up the partial view (which is essentially blank right now), but when I move the mouse off of the popup, it remains. I have to click the close button to get rid of the popup. I've also tried mouseleave vs. mouseout. Why is the popup not closing when I leave it?

**2.**
How do I get the list of skills for a project in my popup? There can be 0 or many skills in each category and I'd like to display them in their own project-skill-category popup (i.e. if a user hovers over the soft skills image related to project 1, it will popup a window with the softSkills for project 1).

Here is the Razor view:

```
<link href="../Content/popup-project-skills.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/popup-project-skills.js"></script>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr class="project-in-list">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.name, "Details", new { id = item.id })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.locationName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
        </td>

        <td align=center class="btn"><img src="../../Content/images/check.png" style="visibility: @(item.hasProgrammingSkills ? "visible" : "hidden") "/></td>
        <td align=center class="btn"><img src="../../Content/images/check.png" style="visibility: @(item.hasSoftSkills ? "visible" : "hidden") "/></td>

        <!-- I WANT THESE IN THE POPUP INSTEAD OF PRINTING THEM IN A NEW COLUMN -->
        <td>
            @foreach(var skill in item.programmingSkills)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => skill.skillName)
                @Html.Raw("; ")
            }
            @foreach(var skill in item.softSkills)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => skill.skillName)
                @Html.Raw("; ")
            }
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

And this is the javascript I am using:

```
function loadPopup()
{
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.1"});
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#popupContact").slideDown("fast");
}
function disablePopup()
{
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#popupContact").slideUp("fast");
}
function centerPopup()
{
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    $("#popupContact").css({"position": "absolute","top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,"left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2});
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({"height": windowHeight});
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".btn").mouseover(function()
    {
        centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
    });

    $("#btn").mouseout(function ()             // this does not work -> not sure why
    {
        disablePopup();
    });

    $("#popupContactClose, .c_btn").click(function()
    {
        disablePopup();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a popup have you considered using [jquery UI's tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) object?

It would be a simpler solution I think.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to Question 1:
Try changing:

```
$("#btn").mouseout(function ()
```

to:

```
$(".btn").mouseout(function ()
```

`#` is for id selector while `.` is for class selectors.  You have not assigned an id to those buttons, only classes.

Question 2:
Ill be honest I cannot answer number two off the top of my head and I do not have access to the stuff to test here at work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `.btn` instead `#btn` at js
2. Try split your question to several a smaller one. If i understand you correctly you cna try somethink like this: for each model item you should create a hidden div with id like this `"softSkills" + item.id`. And then every time insert content of this id into you popup div element, jQuery like version: `$('#popupDiv').html($('#softSkills1'))`.
3. Don't use inline css and js
4. `<td align="center" />` - this one is deprecated and again don't use anything that respond to styles outside of the css/less/sass/scss/compass etc.. stylesheet files
5. For future: razor is ugly, bugly and you'll have a headache sometimes when you'll try to understand how and why it doesn't work with big model structure. Plain HTML, Ajax and jsTemplate engines is a future and much more better for portability and debugging